# Can you resolve this problem in context with the use of 'will'?

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense, future-time

> When I have the gems,I will tell you.
>
> When I will have the gems,I will tell you.

The first one seems incorrect to a non-native speaker like me.But it is used by native speakers.How do the sentences differ?

An example:*I will do when I have the rest.*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'When' clause suggests an actual case, not one's will.

In other words, the listener expects the news about gems after one actually gets the gems, not after one plans to get the gems.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's example *When I have the gems, I will tell you,* it's completely unidiomatic to cast the primary clause in future tense *(when I **will** have them)*, even though *semantically* that would seem to make sense (since I don't have them yet, but I ***will*** have them at some point in the future).

I think this "requirement" to use Present Tense only arises when the point in time referenced by ***when*** hasn't already been identified in preceding text. Consider, for example,...

> *He cannot vote because his birthday isn't until next week, **when he will be** 18*

Most native speakers would use Future Tense there (but it should be noted that Present Tense is at least "acceptable" in that exact context, whereas Future Tense  is *never* really okay in OP's context).